# In VS 2008 one of the ascx file saves very slow but other ascx files are working fine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn

One of the ascx file saves very slow in source (html) mode but other files in same project are working fine. I have deleted this file from my working copy and created a new file with the same name but it is also very slow in saving. I have also created a new ascx file and pasted script of corrupted file in this new file and here this script is saving fine. There is some problem with that particular file. I am using SVN &, I think, I am facing this problem after updating my code from SVN but I am not sure, there might be something else.

The important point is other files are working OK except this one. If someone can help!

EDIT: This file is working fine in test project.

Answer (score 1):

Create a test project and add this file to it. If it will work fine there, possibly there's problem with SVN. If so, then maybe you should recreate repository.